# Compiling project in Linux terminal doesn't work

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface

I have a `Compile.sh` file.
This one works like a charm:

```
cd src
javac model/JNIResultSet.java
javah -jni model.JNIResultSet
cp model_JNIResultSet.h ./../bin/
cd ..

cd bin

gcc -fPIC -o libspieler.so -shared -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/include/ SharedTable.c -lc

java -Djava.library.path=./../bin/ app.Main
```

My problem is that I don't want to have my sources in the bin folder.
I want to have them in a separate folder.
For that my script looks like this one:

```
cd src
javac model/JNIResultSet.java
javah -jni model.JNIResultSet
cp model_JNIResultSet.h ./../data/
cd ..

cd data

gcc -fPIC -o libspieler.so -shared -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/include/ SharedTable.c -lc
cd ..
cd bin
java -Djava.library.path=./../data/ app.Main
```

I don't know why this one isn't working. I get no exception but the program also doesn't work correctly. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Is "libspeiler.so" created in both cases?  Or, what is the compiler error?  What code are you using to load the .so?

Comment: There is no error.. The C project should read from a txt file. If I have the sources in the bin folder it works, if I have them in a separate folder the table is empty without changing the code

Comment: step through with a debugger and see what's going awry with the new version.. my first guess would be a relative file path is now busted somehow.

Comment: use `make` instead of a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working script has:

```
cd bin
gcc -fPIC -o libspieler.so -shared -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/include/ SharedTable.c
```

And the other version has:

```
cd data
gcc -fPIC -o libspieler.so -shared -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/include/ SharedTable.c -lc
```

So `SharedTable.c` must be in the `bin` directory, and the `gcc` command can't find it because it's no longer in the current directory.  Try
using a relative path instead:

```
gcc -fPIC -o libspieler.so -shared -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/include/ ../bin/SharedTable.c -lc
```